# Incorrect hover using jQuery insertBefore

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I'm working on an interactive element that requires the user to sort paragraphs into the correct order by clicking one paragraph, and then clicking a second paragraph to insert the first one before or after the second (depending on whether they're moving a paragraph up or down the list)

http://jsfiddle.net/5ZQkz/2/

My problem is that when a paragraph has been moved into a different place, the hover state for the second paragraph clicked stays active - even though that paragraph is not being hovered over. This happens until the mouse is moved, at which point the correct paragraph is showing the hover state.

E.g Click on paragraph 1, then on paragraph 2. The paragraphs switch positions but the hover state is still active on paragraph 2, despite the mouse hovering over paragraph 1. **Note - this issue does not appear in firefox.**

Any ideas?

```
function swapParas(node1, node2) {
if (node1.index() > node2.index()) node1.insertBefore(node2);
else node1.insertAfter(node2);
node1.hide().fadeIn();
node1.removeClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.selected:hover {
  background:green;
}
```

Try the above code.

Hope this is what you wanted.

Here's an IE fix. Looks odd, but that's about the best you can get:

```
function swapParas(node1, node2) {
  if (node1.index() > node2.index()) node1.insertBefore(node2);
  else node1.insertAfter(node2);
  node1.removeClass('selected');
  node2.after("<div class='para'>" + node2.html() + "</div>");
  node2.remove();
}
```

Comment: Nope, if you keep the mouse still after moving the paragraphs, there is still an incorrect hover showing.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more what you want to achieve, since I'm not getting you obviously. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle. Click paragraph 1, then paragraph 2 and keep the mouse perfectly still. You'll see that the mouse is hovering over paragraph 1, but paragraph 2 is showing the hover state.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I ask this because it works differently on my environment. Clicking 1, keeping mouse still, paragraphs switch, paragraph 1 is showing hover state, which is expected behavior, I guess. Browser is newest FFox.

Comment: I think it's the fadeIn() that's causing the issue. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I'm still looking out for a solution, interesting issue :)

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I've found a workaround for IE browsers. Hope it helps. Cheers.

Comment: Happening in Chrome as well tho.. Does this works for chrome too?

Comment: Works for me in chrome :-)

Comment: Works without hotfix in Chrome. Works in ALL browsers, excluding, guess what - IE...